# Implement cache as distributed between two war files

Tags: java, servlets

i have 2 war files running on tomcat, a.war and b.war since i am new to cache implementation.
i want to make a common cache mechanism between these 2 wars. So that when ever any of the war calls the cache ,it should be common.

There is no framework for the application i am working, its purely on servlets

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracles Coherence Cache .

http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH35UG/Configuring+and+Using+Coherence+Extend